# Implement loop into template parser

Tags: php

I am building a very lightweight framework and would like a custom template parser. I of course know about other solutions such as Smarty, however that is much overkill for what I need.

I've built simple template parsers before but never figured out how to use loops. I am thinking something on the idea of Smarty's foreach loops, or maybe phpBB's loop blocks. Unfortunately I don't really have time right now to paw through those applications, so what is the simplest way to implement loops into a template parser?

It must be able to handle multi-dimensional arrays as well.

Comment: Try it first, and then ask when you get stuck - with examples.  Otherwise, pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: I'm only looking for a push in the right direction. I don't really know what to try first, to be honest. I've done some googleing but can't really find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

go for phpkerby I think that would be solution to your problem

> [PHP KIRBY](http://getkirby.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea of how to do it...

You need to set up your loop start and ending parameters.  So something like:

```
{LOOP_START:users}
    <p>{name}</p>
{LOOP_END:users}
```

Then in your template code, you want to grab the loop placeholder from `{LOOP_START:users}` to `{LOOP_END:users}`.  You also want to grab a snippet of everything between those tags.  Loop through your array and replace the vars in the snippet, then replace the whole placeholder with your new output.  Here's the basic idea:

```
$output = your_method_to_get_the_full_template_contents();
$loop_with_tags = your_method_to_find_the_loop_tags_and_content($output, 'users');
$loop_inside_tags = your_method_to_get_the_loop_contents($loop_with_tags);

$loop_output = '';
foreach($users as $user) {
    $loop_output .= str_replace(array_keys($user), array_values($user), $loop_inside_tags);
}

$output = str_replace($loop_with_tags, $loop_output, $output);
```